# Jquery getting checked items returns unchecked boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has been driving me crazy for hours.  I'm trying to get an array with the values of all "checked" checkboxes when "All" is selected.  For some reason, on my site, when I check "All" it returns an empty set, but when I uncheck it the correct values are returned.

The craziest part is that I made a CodePen with the stripped down code and it works as expected, and I can't figure out what is different about my site.

The checkbox is the one above the States that says "All" here: https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/climateIndicators/table

```js
//check all state checkboxes
$('#all_states').click(function() {
  checkCheckboxes(this.id, 'all_states__checkboxes');
});

function checkCheckboxes(id, pID) {
  $('#' + pID).find(':checkbox').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).prop('checked', $('#' + id).is(':checked'));
  });
}

//state filter
$('.state_checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var search = [];
  $('.state_sub_checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    var group = $(this).val();
    search.push(group.trim());
  });
  console.log(search);

});
```

````html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
My HTML code: ```
<div class="px-3 py-3">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group form-check mb-2">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input state_checkbox" id="all_states">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="All">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row pl-3" id="all_states__checkboxes">
      <div class="col-lg">
        <div class="form-group form-check mb-0">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input state_sub_checkbox" value="CT" id="Connecticut">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="Connecticut">Connecticut</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check mb-0">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input state_sub_checkbox" value="ME" id="Maine">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="Maine">Maine</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check mb-0">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input state_sub_checkbox" value="MA" id="Massachussetts">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="Massachussetts">Massachussetts</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg">
        <div class="form-group form-check mb-0">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input state_sub_checkbox" value="NH" id="NewHampshire">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="NewHampshire">New Hampshire</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check mb-0">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input state_sub_checkbox" value="NY" id="NewYork">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="NewYork">New York</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check mb-0">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input state_sub_checkbox" value="VT" id="NewYork">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="Vermont">Vermont</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
````

Comment: in this snippet its working as expected

Comment: It appears your question is entirely about the debug attempt - *when I check "All" it returns an empty set* - where [it] is your console.log?  As your tickboxes work ok on your site.

Comment: The issue is that `$('.state_sub_checkbox:checked')` runs *before* they have been checked, so is an empty array.  Open browser tools (F12) - ctrl-shift-f for find in sources - look for search.push - add breakpoint (click on line) - observer what happens in the UI / sources as you click the "all" tickbox.  **edit** in your snippet at `debugger;` in the click event handler

Comment: can you try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pz2v4L1y/) ? I have merge both handler in one.

Comment: Do what you've done in your fiddle - put them both in the same event handler

Comment: offtopic: your `<label for="all"` doesn't point to the checkbox as there's no element with id `all`

Comment: Or you could raise a new, custom event after you've ticked all the boxes (at the end of `checkCheckboxes`) and have your filter code listen for that event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#all_states__checkboxes').on('click', function() {
  const all= $('[type=checkbox]',this).length
  const checked = $('[type=checkbox]:checked',this).length
  $('#all_states').prop('checked', all===checked);
});
$('#all_states').on('click',function() {
  $('#all_states__checkboxes [type=checkbox]').attr('checked',this.checked)
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  The issue was that on my site I had the check checkboxes function after the function checking if they were checked.  When I copied into the codepen I had switched the order.